# Trouble code Tabs?

Tags: html, css, tabs

I got a new Member ....
I have a problem with the Web programming that cannot be resolved.
The problem code that I hastt anything Tabs just do not ...

http://8pic.ir/images/mrghe6ey1a8wkbxjefzw.png

Now my own Tabs. And the HTML code and Style and I entered the picture. But I do want to Mote ...
Now what do I enter HTML code and Style that looks like above it:

This bug check codes from?
These codes are related to Tabs.

http://Trainbit.com/files/1222191884/Tabs_Style_amp_HTML.txt

HTML:

```
<div class="list-wrap">
<div class="post-list">
<div class="img-box">
<img src="/<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/image/1.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-slider">
                    <a href="#">Permalink to Post With Featured</a>
                    <br/>
                    2014 17 June
                    </div>                   
</div>
<div class="post-list">
<div class="img-box">
<img src="/<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/image/1.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-slider">
                    <a href="#">Permalink to Post With Featured</a>
                    <br/>
                    2014 17 June
                    </div>                   
</div>
</div>
<div class="post-list">
<div class="img-box">
<img src="/<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/image/1.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-slider">
                    <a href="#">Permalink to Post With Featured</a>
                    <br/>
                    2014 17 June
                    </div>                   
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.img-box{
    width:89px;
    height:89px;
    margin:10px 10px;
    float:left;
    padding-left:-5px;
    }
.img-box img{
    width:89px;
    height:89px;
    float:left;
    }
.text-slider{
    margin:10px;
    font-size:11px;
    float:right;
    }
.post-list a{
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:13px;
    color:#7b7c7c;
    float:right;
    }
.text-slider a:hover{
    color:#54d5d5;
    }
```

Thank you I will submit an answer:)

Comment: I'm assuming that English is not your first language; would it be possible to have someone whose skill with the English language you trust to review your question (in your native language) and see if they could offer a better translation? As it is, I have no idea what the problem is.

Comment: You want each of your list entries to stack vertically, but right now they're flowing incorrectly and doing weird things with images.  Am I on track with this?

Comment: Hi ... Sorry for bad English writing ....

Comment: @ndm13:If you want to view the first photo look like the picture on the left and the right and left image to see list And now I want to be a vertical list of thumbnails on the left and on the left is written Tabs left is the exact opposite ...

Comment: Is my answer solving your problem, or is the issue different?  View the JSFiddle and if it's not what you're looking for maybe we can try to clarify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got your problem fixed.  You have to specify a width and height for your `<div>`s to work the way you want them to.  See this: http://jsfiddle.net/P6gkx/

HTML:

```
<div class="list-wrap">
    <div class="post-list">
        <div class="img-box">
            <img src="/<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/image/1.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="text-slider"> <a href="#">Permalink to Post With Featured</a>

            <br/>2014 17 June</div>
    </div>
    <div class="post-list">
        <div class="img-box">
            <img src="/<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/image/1.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="text-slider"> <a href="#">Permalink to Post With Featured</a>

            <br/>2014 17 June</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="post-list">
    <div class="img-box">
        <img src="/<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/image/1.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="text-slider"> <a href="#">Permalink to Post With Featured</a>

        <br/>2014 17 June</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.img-box {
    width:89px;
    height:89px;
    margin:10px 10px;
    float:left;
    padding-left:-5px;
}
.img-box img {
    width:89px;
    height:89px;
    float:left;
}
.text-slider {
    margin:10px;
    font-size:11px;
    float:left;
}
.post-list a {
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:13px;
    color:#7b7c7c;
    float:left;
}
.text-slider a:hover {
    color:#54d5d5;
}

.post-list{
    width:310px;
    display:block;
    height:120px;
    background-color:#ddd;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the balance of the list after the width and height of the code do? 
Example, you wrote:.post-list{
 width:314px;
 height:110px;
    display:block;
    background-color:#ddd;
    margin-bottom:2px;
}

Comment: Essentially you're making a box for your post to be in.  Before the box could be as big as it wanted to be, and that was causing problems.  Now that it has dimensions, things fit where they're supposed to.

Comment: Again, pre-built box to define the width and height you not pour me out again?

Comment: I'm sorry, having some trouble understanding.  If you're talking about not having overflow, you could set `overflow:hidden` or something like that.  If you want it to overflow, that will be more work.  I don't know where it would overflow to.

Comment: You would add it to `.post-list{}`